# Converting a string with commas to double and int are different. Why?

Tags: c#, string, int, double

I am migrating from an old MFC GUI to C#.

I was building a Form-based GUI when I've got an unexpected exception converting a string to an integer type. I assumed it would work the same as converting string to double.

```
string str = "1,000";
double dthou = Convert.ToDouble(str);   // OK
int ithou = Convert.ToInt32(str);       // raises an exception
```

Conversion to double gives correct value: 1000.0.
For int conversion, I was able to get a solution : [Convert.ToInt32() a string with Commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824326/convert-toint32-a-string-with-commas).

But I am curious if there were any reason behind this.
Or, am I missing something?

I was able to find a similar, but not exactly a duplicate question :
[Number parsing weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094254/number-parsing-weirdness)

[EDIT] after learning about the culture issue.

I am in a kind of a culture-shock because until now, in Korea, both floating point number and integer numbers are expressed with "," for thousands group and "." for decimal point (at least in the real world, in Korea, I mean, I think... ).
I guess I will have to accept current settings of MS Visual Studio and carry on.

[EDIT2] after sleeping over this issue.

I think it's more of the inconsistent handling of the formatted string.  ToDouble accepts strings with thousands separator (in my culture, comma), but ToInt32 does not.  If `ToDouble` is `float | allowThousands`, then why could'nt `ToInt32` have been `integer | allowThousands` is what I am asking.

Comment: What is your current culture?

Comment: This seems like a culture issue.

Comment: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name tells me "ko-KR"

Comment: _in Korea, both floating point number and integer numbers are expressed with "," for thousands group and "." for decimal point_ That's sound bizarre for it's .net framework culture because it is the opposite in .net world.

Comment: @Keugyeol Updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23243174/447156) after your `[EDIT2]` part..

Comment: @Soner I was implying comma as the thousands separator in my culture. yes, it is still a culture issue, but its more of inconsistency in applying the culture, I may say? I will edit the [EDIT2].

Comment: @Keugyeol _ToDouble accepts strings with thousands separator (in my culture, comma)_ **That's wrong**. `Convert.ToDouble` accepts both decimal separator and thousands seperator since it's using `Float | AllowThousands`. But since your string has comma and comma is thousands seperator in your current culture, it parses it as `1000` not `1`. You asking, why `Convert.ToInt32` doesn't have `Integer | AllowThousands` ?. I don't know but there is an overload of `Int32.Parse` to handle this kind of situations.

Answer (score 4):

For the double conversion, there are two possibilities:

1. In your culture, `,` is the number group separator. And so the conversion succeeds and returns a value of `1000`.
2. Alternatively, in your culture, `,` is used as the decimal separator. Again the conversion to floating point succeeds but this time returns `1`.

For conversion to integer, `"1,000"` is simply not an integer. My suspicion, given your naming, is that `,` is a number group separator for you. And you are expecting it to be treated that way by `ToInt32()`. But `ToInt32()` does not accept number group separators. Valid characters for `ToInt32()` are `0` to `9`, the optional sign prefix of `-` or `+` and leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: With my culture "ko-KR" meaning Korean, conversion to double gives correct value, in this case, 1000.0;

Comment: It depends on what you mean by correct. In France, for instance, the correct answer is `1.0`.

Comment: I have edited the comment to add my culture: "ko-KR", thank you.

Comment: You might care to think about what happens when your code runs on a machine with a different culture.

Comment: _Valid characters for ToInt32() are 0 to 9 and the optional sign prefix of - or +_ **and** leading or trailing white spaces.

Answer (score 3):

In your profile, it says you are from South Korea. That's why I assume your current culture is `ko-KR`. (And you [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242919/converting-a-string-with-commas-to-double-and-int-are-different-why#comment35563306_23242919) as well.)

And it's [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `.` but it's [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `,`

[image]

Your [`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) works and it assumes your `,` is a thousands seperator, not decimal seperator. That's why your `dthou` will be `1000` not `1`.

[`Convert.ToInt32(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses `Int32.Parse(string, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` explicitly and this method [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs#78ffbe1e274ca0bb) like;

```
public static int Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return Number.ParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
}
```

As you can see this method uses [`NumberStyles.Integer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a default. And that's why your string can be successfully parsed only it contasion one of these;

- Leading white space
- Trailing white space
- Leading sign (positive or negative)

And since your string has thousands seperator or decimal seperator (this depends on which one you used for) this method throws exception.

Instead of that, you can use [`Int32.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yaffedz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you can specify your `NumberStyles` like `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint` or `NumberStyles.AllowThousands`

As an example;

```
string str = "1,000";
int ithou = Int32.Parse(str, NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                        new CultureInfo("ko-KR"));
Console.WriteLine(ithou); // Prints 1000
```

If you want to get `1` as a result, you can use [`CultureInfo.Clone` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone.aspx) to your culture and set it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` and `NumberGroupSeparator` properties like;

```
string str = "1,000";
CultureInfo c = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ko-KR").Clone();
c.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
c.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
int dthou = Int32.Parse(str, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, c);
Console.WriteLine(dthou ); // Prints 1
```

> I don't think it's a cultural problem. It is the inconsistent handling
>   of the formatted string. ToDouble accepts strings with comma, but
>   ToInt32 does not. It's like going back to the original question again,
>   but couldn't ToInt32 be implemented to accept the comma just like
>   ToDouble function?

Oh my dear friend, you are still thinking wrong..

Everything is a culture problem in your case. There is no such a thing "*`Convert.ToDouble()` accepts strings with comma, but `Convert.ToInt32()` does not*".

Let's look at one more time how these methods are implemented.

`Convert.ToDouble(string)` uses `Double.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` explicitly and it is [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs#73cc31e0b47fd637) like;

```
public static double Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
{
     return Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float| NumberStyles.AllowThousands, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
}
```

With this `NumberStyles.Float| NumberStyles.AllowThousands`, you can use both decimal point or thousands separator in your code but `,` is your culture's `NumberGroupSeparator` not `NumberDecimalSeparator`. That's why your string will be parsed as a thousands seperetor. **There is no such a thing Convert.ToDouble uses string with comma**. It can be use your current culture's `NumberDecimalSeparator` or `NumberGroupSeparator` depends on which character your string has. If both were equal, `NumberDecimalSeparator` will be dominant and it will be used.

`Convert.ToInt32(string)` uses `Int32.Parse(string, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` explicitly and it's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs#78ffbe1e274ca0bb) like;

```
public static int Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return Number.ParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
}
```

As I said before, `NumberStyles.Integer` allows three things for your string; leading white space, trailing white space and leading positive or negative sign. It can't be parse if your string has decimal separator or thousands separator **no matter it is comma or dot**.

> but couldn't ToInt32 be implemented to accept the comma just like
>   ToDouble function?

I told you before. `Convert.ToInt32` doesn't have an overload takes `NumberStyles` as a parameter. You can use [`Int32.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yaffedz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you can specify your `NumberStyles` enumeration for parsing your decimal separator or thousands separator.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. After knowing the inner workings of ToInt32(), I wonder if it could have been NumberStyles.AllowThousands instead of NumberStyles.Integer in the ParseInt32 function argument.

Comment: @Keugyeol Updated my answer. Take a look at. If you used `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` without any change in your culture, it's beeing parsed as thousands seperators and result will be `1000`. If you `Clone` your culture and set it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` and `NumberGroupSeparator` as you want, you can get `1` as a result with `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint` enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

In the english culture the decimal sign is "." . In the swedish culture the decimal sigh is ",". The myriad sign can be " ", "," or ".". So that's why C# throws an exception when the decimal sign is different than its culture specified.

Comment: As far as I know, comma is used the same for both floating and integer expressions in Korea, and I was unexpectedly caught when one of the conversion threw an exception.